# OSX Screencapturing using AVScreenCaptureInput

Tags: c++, objective-c, macos, avfoundation

In my mac application i need to grab screen and send it to otherend,

Is it possible by [AVCaptureSession](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureSession_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/AVCaptureSession) ?

if Yes, i just need RGB or YUV data not the audio , is it possible to configure it  ?

if not AVFoundation class/framework , then which one is recommended ?

Comment: Do you need a single screenshot or a continuous stream?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a continuous stream of yuv images, you can do something like this:

```
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

@interface ScreenCapture() <AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate>

@property (nonatomic) AVCaptureSession *captureSession;

@end

@implementation ScreenCapture

- (instancetype)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.captureSession = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];

        AVCaptureScreenInput *input = [[AVCaptureScreenInput alloc] initWithDisplayID:CGMainDisplayID()];
        [self.captureSession addInput:input];

        AVCaptureVideoDataOutput *output = [[AVCaptureVideoDataOutput alloc] init];
        [self.captureSession addOutput:output];

        // TODO: create a dedicated queue.
        [output setSampleBufferDelegate:self queue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];

        [self.captureSession startRunning];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection {
    // sampleBuffer contains screen cap, for me it's yuv
}

@end
```

This gives me about ~15fps. You can get higher frame rates by lowering the minimum frame rate:

```
input.minFrameDuration = CMTimeMake(1, 60);
```

For a more mature implementation, which more error checking, see Apple's [AVScreenShack sample code](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/AVScreenShack).